# MFSK symbol synchronization

Tags: fsk, symbol-timing

I am working on a simple MFSK modem for use on the HF band. I'm having trouble recovering the symbol timing information from the stream.

With 2-FSK it's easy - just subtract one frequency from the other, and use the 0-crossing point to determine how far off you are (ideally, the 0-crossing point should be right in between 2 symbols)

I'm unsure how to scale this up to more than 2 frequencies. Is there a standard way that symbol synchronization is performed on MFSK signals that I could look into?

Here is a graph of one of my 4-FSK signals, with some noised added in. Each colour represents one of the different frequency bins of interest. The pink lines are the center of each symbol.

[image]

Comment: what's the vertical axis in this? If it is decibel, then it would look like you have an SNR of 200 dB – which would be quite surprisingly good. But it would make things a lot easier if the SNR is this good!

Comment: @MarcusMüller This is the raw output from the FFT. The unit is effectively meaningless as it depends on the analog signal magnitude itself.

Comment: a negative magnitude?

Comment: @MarcusMüller My apologies, I uploaded the wrong image. I've corrected it now

Comment: nice, this looks a lot more challenging. I assume the red, yellow and green traces are wide because you were observing multple frequencies being active?

Comment: They're wide because there happened to be 2 of the same symbols consecutively.

Comment: Is the tan inverse available?

Comment: @gotchi85 I don't see why not. I guess I was hoping/assuming there was an existing algorithm for synchronization I could use (MFSK isn't a new concept)

Comment: You can calculate the tan inverse of your baseband signal to get the phase. Substracting symbol n to n+1 on the unwrapped phase, you get the instantaneous frequency moving through M levels, 4 in the case of a 4-FSK. From here, you can find transitions and thus timing

Comment: Sorry, substracting samples... and it works with a continuous phase

Comment: IIRC the Mueller and Mueller Timing Error Detector (in a symbol Timing recovery PLL) works with baseband pulses with M levels symmetrical around 0.  You'll need to peak the symbol with a pulse matched filter ahead of it.  Be advised the M&M TED doesn't work well on "clock pattern" preambles; its TED gain flattens out to 0 on such symbol sequences.